# How to get JSONArray from WebService using Asynctask

Tags: android, json

I want to ask I have some JSON file returning from WebService I can detect some returning from JSON file but if I want to get JSON array from there cannot do that? But if do that manually like I only use JSON returning from flat data without Asynctask and same returning but can detect.

Problem is: If I use returning JSON file from WebService array cannot be detected on there
But if I use flat data and have same return can detected array

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Please post what you have tried and error occur.